# React Native navigator close event?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm still new to react native and I'm currently trying to learn how to do transition in and out. So far I use the "onNavigationStateChange" to trigger the transition in, but I kept on searching and I can't seem to find any documentation for these events especially to handle when the user used the back button to go back to the previous page (I'm using stack navigator).

Is there some hidden documentation somewhere where I can see the list of events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your transitioning on [`StackNavigator`'s config](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig).

> - `transitionConfig` - Function to return an object that is merged with the default screen transitions (take a look at `TransitionConfig`
>     in [type definitions](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/flow/react-navigation.js)). Provided function will be passed the
>     following arguments:
>
>   - `transitionProps` - Transition props for the new screen.
>   - `prevTransitionProps` - Transitions props for the old screen.
>   - `isModal` - Boolean specifying if screen is modal.
> - `onTransitionStart` - Function to be invoked when the card transition animation is about to start.
> - `onTransitionEnd` - Function to be invoked once the card transition animation completes.

Comment: Will look into this, thanks. BTW is it possible to animate a child component? I have two Views inside the parent view. One is a semi-transparent background which I intend to animate the opacity, and the other one which I intend to animate to move from left to right.

Comment: @JeremyLayson [React-Native animations documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html)